# Refreshing a previously called class's property

Tags: c#, winforms

Say, i have called a class in my mainform, like

```
BSPclass bsp = new BSPclass();
```

In that class there is 1 property like,

```
class BSPclass 
{ 
    public string p1 = "player1";
}
```

Then, if i click a button in mainform, a new form (as form2) will appear, 
say, there is a textbox which will set a value for p1 (also BSPclass was called in form2 too)

```
private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    BSP.p1 = txtbox.text;
}
```

Now, problem is, if I close the form2, it doesn't show the neew value of p1 in mainform, still shows "player1"

How to refresh or do other anything?

Comment: Where did you created `BSP` instance? If it's created in `form2` and it's as well disposed along with the form.

Comment: I created BSP instance in both forms, cuz mainform or form1 was run first, form2 run later and closed after adding a value to p1

Comment: Both the instances are different here. You will have to pass it to main form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on where did you created `BSP` instance? If it's created in `form2` then it's as well disposed along with the form. Both the instances are different here. You will have to pass it to main form using a delegate something like:

Say your main form have a insance of `BSPclass` like  `BSPclass bsp = new BSPclass();`

In you `form2` declare a delegate like

```
public delegate void passinfotomainform(string data);
```

Create a event of that delegate type

```
public event passinfotomainform datapassevent;
```

Then in button click raise the event

```
private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
BSP.p1 = txtbox.text;
if(datapassevent != null)
 datapassevent(txtbox.text);
}
```

In main form, register this event like

```
form2.datapassevent += new EventHandler(myhandler);
```

In `myhandler` get the data

```
private void myhandler(string arg)
{
  bsp.p1 = arg; //set the bsp in main form
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the value of textbox to mainform and then refresh p1. You shouldn't create an instance of BSPClass in form2. See code below:

In form2:

```
public string pTemp;
private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    pTemp = txtbox.text;
}
```

In mainform:

```
BSPclass bsp = new BSPclass();
Form2 f=new Form2();
f.ShowDialog(this);
bsp.p=f.pTemp;
```